# How to show category name of classified listing in social engine

Tags: socialengine

i am working on social engine create a form in admin panel to post ad its display in frontend but when i add category all fields are dispaly but category not show how to show category name on my ad listing..

```
  This is my listing frontend...
```

[image]

```
 This is my form to crete ad..in frontend
```

[image]

```
  This is my category which is add from backend and dispaly in frontend form when you create ad then choose category ...
```

[image]

So please suggest me how to show my category in my ad listing..

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below answer will helps you.

```
$categoryObject = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('categories', 'classified')->find($classified->category_id)->current();

$categoryName = $categoryObject->category_name;
```

** In above code $classified is the object of Classified_Model_Classified class. You can also optimize the above code if you want to use the category name only (you need to fetch the category name only).

** I am assuming that your are using the SocialEngine - Classified module and you did not do any modification in given structure by SocialEngine, because in this case the below answer may leads to error.